# SFTP error - User does not have any roots specified

Tags: sftp

Any idea what would case the error **The user <> does not have any roots specified; the channel is being closed** when I login to an SFTP site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My password expired and rather than informing me of this fact, the server kicked out the "user does not have any root specified message". Go figure!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a permissions problem. Check to see if the user has access rights to their "root" or "home" folder.